# How to convert a jQuery each() call acting on a #id into pure javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery code which initializes the prototype class using jquery like this:

```
var sliders = [];
$('#slider').each(function() {
sliders.push(new Slider(this))
})
```

I need to convert this into pure Javascript code for initializing `Slider` prototype class.
can anyone help it? I'm not good with javascript..

Comment: You shouldn't call .each on an #id, it should be unique. However, this is simply looping through a set of elements on popping them onto an array. Basic JavaScript and you should try some stuff before asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there can only be 1 id on a page, which makes it a lot simpler...

```
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var sliders = [ new Slider(slider) ];
```